# Desativar Combo select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Caros;

Tentei em diversas formas dar o disable do combo Select (mespgto) quando o checkBox (radio04) estiver ticado "checked==true", porem sem sucesso. Poderiam me ajudar?

Obs: Da forma que está a função (liberar), ele chega apenas a travar o combo select, e não é o comportamento esperado.

Segue trecho do código:

```
     <script>

     function liberar() {

    if  (document.getElementById('radios03').checked==true)
    {
    document.getElementById('parcela').disabled=false
    }



    if  ( document.getElementById('radios04').checked==true)
    {
          document.getElementById('parcela').disabled=true

          document.getElementById('parcela').value=""

          document.getElementById('mespgto).disabled=true
    }

   }

    </script>



    <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Parcelado: </label>  

  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio" onchange="liberar();">
    <label for="radios-0">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radios03" value="Sim" >
      Sim
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="radio" onchange="liberar();">
    <label for="radios-1">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radios04" value="Nao" checked="checked">
      Não

    </label>
    <p>
    </div>

 <label><input  type="text" disabled id="parcela" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" name="parcela" maxlength="2"  style="width:50px;"  class="form-control input-md">
 Máximo 12 parcelas
  </label>
  <p id="saida"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<form name="mespgto" >
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios">Meio de Parcelamento:</label>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  <select class="mespgto" id="mespgto" name="financeiro" >
  <option  disabled selected>Selecione</option>
  <option value="xxx" id="xxx"   >xxx</option>
  <option value="yyy" id="yyy"  >yyy</option>
  <option value="www" id="www"  >Santander www</option>
  <option value="outros" id="outros"   >Outro</option>

  </select>
</div>
</div>
</form>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta-te uma `'` na linha `document.getElementById('mespgto).disabled=true` [exemplo no fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tk5fbLs/)

```
function liberar() {

  if (document.getElementById('radios03').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('parcela').disabled = false
  }

  if (document.getElementById('radios04').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('parcela').disabled = true
    document.getElementById('parcela').value = "";
    document.getElementById('mespgto').disabled=true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Boa MoshMage, na verdade foi um erro de copy paste, mas eu estava errando na logica, na função liberar, onde eu corrigi agora. Sabe aquele método infalível onde vc para de fazer quando n consegue resolver e volta depois de algumas horas e percebe que estava errando em algo simples? então foi isso...abraços.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Parcelado: </label>  

      <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="radio" onchange="liberar();">
        <label for="radios-0">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radios03" value="Sim" >
          Sim
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="radio" onchange="liberar();">
        <label for="radios-1">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radios04" value="Nao" checked="checked">
          Não

        </label>
        <p>
        </div>

     <label><input  type="number" disabled id="parcela"  name="parcela" maxlength="2"  style="width:50px;"  class="form-control input-md">
     Máximo 12 parcelas
      </label>
      <p id="saida"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form name="mespgto" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios">Meio de Parcelamento:</label>

      <div class="col-md-4">
      <select class="mespgto" id="mespgto" name="financeiro" >
      <option  disabled selected>Selecione</option>
      <option value="xxx" id="xxx"   >xxx</option>
      <option value="yyy" id="yyy"  >yyy</option>
      <option value="www" id="www"  >Santander www</option>
      <option value="outros" id="outros"   >Outro</option>

      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>`


         <script>

         function liberar() {

            document.getElementById('parcela').disabled=true
            if  (document.getElementById('radios03').checked==true)
            {
                document.getElementById('parcela').disabled=false
            }


            document.getElementById('parcela').disabled=false

            document.getElementById('parcela').value=""

            document.getElementById('mespgto').disabled=false

            if  ( document.getElementById('radios04').checked==true)
            {
                  document.getElementById('parcela').disabled=true

                  document.getElementById('parcela').value=""

                  document.getElementById('mespgto').disabled=true
            }

           }

        </script>
```